# Describe the surface defined by $\frac{x^2}4 + y^2 - 2x - 10y - z^2 + 41 = 0$

Tags: calculus

> Describe the surface defined by $\frac{x^2}4 + y^2 - 2x - 10y - z^2 + 41 = 0$

I was looking through the possible surfaces that could match this equation but couldn't figure out which one it resembled the most. I was in between a hyperboloid of one sheet and a hyperboloid of two sheets.

Comment: It is $\dfrac{(x-4)^2}{4}+(y-5)^2=12+z^2$ so the intersection of every $xy$-plane with this surface is an ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

Given equation, $$S: \cfrac{x^2}{4}+y^2 -2x-10y-z^2+41=0$$  $$ \Rightarrow \biggl(\cfrac{x^2}{4} -\cfrac{8x}{4} +\cfrac{16}{4} \biggr) + (y^2 - 10y + 25) -z^2 + 12 = 0$$  $$\Rightarrow \cfrac{(x-4)^2}{4} + (y-5)^2  = z^2 -  12$$

For $z \in ( -2 \sqrt{3},2 \sqrt{3}) $ there won't be any surface, so the chances for hyperboloid of one sheet goes out, hence the given equation is of hyperboloid of two sheet with elliptical cross-section.
[image]

I would advice you to rely on analytical method, because you won't have luxury of Graphers in exam.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is such a visual question:  so just plot it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no cross terms, so this surface is just a translation of $\frac14x^2+y^2-z^2+k=0$ for some as-yet unknown $k$. The pattern of signs on the left-hand side shows that this some type of hyperboloid; whether it is one- or two-sheeted (or degenerate) depends on the sign of $k$.

There are couple of basic approaches for determining $k$. You could complete the squares for $x$ and $y$, obtaining $$\left(\frac x2-2\right)^2+(y-5)^2-z^2+12 = 0,$$ so this is a hyperboloid of two sheets. Alternatively, you can find the center of this quadric through various means such as differentiation (although in this case it can be done by inspection). Substituting the coordinates of the center into the expression on the left-hand side of the quadric’s equation gives you the value of $k$ after translation of the center to the origin. A related way to find $k$ is to assemble the coefficients of the original equation into the associated matrix $$Q=\begin{bmatrix}\frac14&0&0&-1\\0&1&0&-10\\0&0&-1&0\\-1&10&0&41\end{bmatrix}.$$ Letting $Q_3$ be the upper-left $3\times3$ submatrix of $Q$, $k=\det(Q)/\det(Q_3)$. (This comes from the fact that translation to the center eliminates the linear terms without affecting $\det Q$.) The determinant of $Q$ looks relatively easy to compute by expanding along the third row/column.